# Date/time output in Oracle SQL (BI Publisher)

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence

I am trying to output the date (day/mon/yr) without the (hr:min:sec) in the string in oracle BI Publisher.  I have tried several different methods of formatting, but nothing seems to work.  Here is my code:

```
select   "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" as "DATE_OF_AVG",
     "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."VALUE" as "DAILY_AVG_VALUE" 
 from    "TEST"."CALCULATED_DATA_POINT" "CALCULATED_DATA_POINT",
     "TEST"."DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG" 
 where   "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."CALCULATED_DATA_POINT_ID"="CALCULATED_DATA_POINT"."ID"
  and    "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."SITE_ID" in ('123abc') 
   and   "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" between ('01-FEB-17') and ('28-FEB-17') 
   and   "CALCULATED_DATA_POINT"."NAME" ='test_uptime'
order by "DATA_POINT_DAILY_AVG"."DATE_OF_AVG" DESC;
```

Here is my current output:

```
DATE_OF_AVG                         DAILY_AVG_VALUE
-------------------------------     ---------------
(2017-02-28T00:00:00.000+00:00)             100
(2017-02-27T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-26T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-25T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-22T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-21T00:00:00.000+00:00)              94
(2017-02-20T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-19T00:00:00.000+00:00)              99
(2017-02-18T00:00:00.000+00:00)             100
```

Expected output:

```
DATE_OF_AVG DAILY_AVG_VALUE
----------- ---------------
28-FEB-17           100
27-FEB-17            99
26-FEB-17            99
25-FEB-17            99
22-FEB-17            99
21-FEB-17            94
20-FEB-17            99
19-FEB-17            99
18-FEB-17           100
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to_char(date_col, 'DD-MON-YY')

Comment: Thank you Roger!  It was exactly what I needed.